# What Type of ViewController To Make?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a button that when pressed, brings up a modal view.

Lets call this modal view "AboutViewController".

My question is, what type of viewController should this be.  I set up the rest of my app a while ago and don't remember exactly how I got it setup.

I already have a TabBar that is present so Ill just make it viewable at the bottom, that shouldn't be an issue.

But I want it to be a navController but I want it to be separate from the nav stack of the rest of my app, I will then add a UITable, etc in IB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add that view as a PresentModalViewController. You have to add that view as same as we are adding the other view in our project.

And then after when button is pressed you have to write below code to show that view.

```
AboutViewController *aboutViewController = [[AboutViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AboutViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:aboutViewController animated:YES];
[aboutViewController release];
```

Comment: Thanks Jay, I actually already have all this setup, my question was how should I setup AboutViewController so that it has a navstack of its own

Comment: Means can u tell me in detail actually where you have to add that view and in stack or you want as a sub navigationview controller. Tell me in detail....

Comment: Ok sure, I have a regular view (what it is irrelevant) that has a button in the navigation bar titled "about".  When I click this button, I have it set to bring up a modal view of `AboutViewController`.  In this `AboutViewController`, I want to have a table view.  When I click a cell, it should go to detail view and result in back button on navigation bar.  I know how to do all this except I need help to create AboutViewController because I just forgot how I did it before.

Comment: No, I tried creating this already and everything worked except that when I tried to add a done button to the nav bar through code, it didnt work.  So now I'm just trying to start from scratch.

Comment: `UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:nil]; 
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton; 
    [doneButton release];` The button is not showing on the bar when I run it.

Comment: UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(MethodName Which you Want To call)]; self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton; [doneButton release];    
"Don't Put nil there...."

Comment: Yeah, but the button should still show, but it shouldn't do anything when clicked.  IT is not showing at all though.  I just put a method in and its still not showing.

Comment: can u came in the chat room ?

Comment: just type iphone in the search and came in iphone / ipad room

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:AboutViewController];
[self presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];
```

Comment: I already have a method to push modally to aboutViewController.  I just need to setup the actual view controller.

Comment: I think edc1591 is suggesting

@interface AboutViewController : UINavigationController {
}

Comment: Ok, so lets say I do `@interface AboutViewController : UINavigationController`, then is there anything in IB that I need to setup related to the navbar left?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a class for the Modal View? Say you called it AboutViewController.

You would just need to do:

```
    AboutViewController *viewController = [[AboutViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    [viewController release];

    [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
    [navController release];
```

The nav stack for the Modal View will be separate from your other nav stack and your Modal View Controller will handle it.

Comment: I got error `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported`

Comment: What class are you using for your AboutViewController? That class should be UIViewController or a subclass of it. And should also have a .xib file for it.

Comment: ahh ic, I set it up as UINavController, ill switch it back